# Concept of square in multivariate statistics

Tags: multivariate-analysis, linear-algebra, univariate

This might be more of a linear algebra question, but here we go.

I have always been confused about how the concept of squares in  $\mathbb{R}^1$ sometimes corresponds to a matrix product $A^{T}A$ and sometimes to $AA^{T}$ in multivariate statistics. Is there any intuitive, general reason for this, or is it just something you would have to derive in the specific setting?

An example:
The univariate delta-rule result in a normal distribution with variance $[g'(\theta)]^2\sigma^2$. The multivariate case yield the covariance matrix $\nabla g(\theta)^T\Sigma \nabla g(\theta)$. When it comes to covariance, however, we see that the univariate concept of $var(aX)=a^2var(X)$ corresponds to the multivariate $cov(AX)=Acov(X)A^T$. That is, the seemingly similar examples yield different interpretations of the square in higher dimensions, in that one is on the form $A^TXA$ while the other is on the form $AXA^T$.

Comment: Hi: if X is symmetric ( which is the case if it's a covariance matrix ) , they are equivalent so that may be  why you see have seen both notations. If X is not symmetric and the original expression is AX, then the second A is transposed.

Comment: You need transpositions to ensure that you'll get a scalar in the end. When you have an equation involving not square matrices, you can usually even guess what's transposed what not, just based on the idea that you have correct dimensions of the results

Answer (score 0):

At first, we need to agree that $X$ is $k$ dimensional random column vector,
$$X=\left(\begin{matrix}X_1\\X_2\\...\\X_k\end{matrix}\right)$$ and $Var(X) = \Sigma$ is $k\times k$ matrix.

If $A$ is $1 \times k$ row vector, i.e., $A=\left(\begin{matrix}a_1&a_2&...&a_k\end{matrix}\right)$, then we have $Var(AX) = A\Sigma A^T$.

If A is define as $k \times 1$ column vector, i.e., $A=\left(\begin{matrix}a_1\\a_2\\...\\a_k\end{matrix}\right)$, then we have $Var(A^TX) = A^T\Sigma A$.